# saving, deleting and fetching data from a one to many relationship core data

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, one-to-many

I have created a data model like so:

I have this code for a fetch request:

```
func roundFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Customer")
    print("Check here: \(myRoundIndexPath)")
    //let predicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "custRoundRel = %@", frc2.objectAtIndexPath(myRoundIndexPath!) as! RoundName) //ASSUME THIS IS CORRECT
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "c2fna", ascending: true)
    //fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
```

My commented out code does not give an error, but I cannot seem to save a customer to the RoundName instance. When I save a customer with its attributes, I have used this code:

```
func newCust() {
    let cont = self.context
    let newCustomer = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Customer", inManagedObjectContext: cont)
    let aCust = Customer(entity: newCustomer!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: cont)

    aCust.c2fna = firstName.text
    aCust.c3lna = lastName.text
    aCust.c4tel = tel.text
    aCust.c5mob = mob.text
    aCust.c6ema = email.text
    aCust.c7hsn = houseNo.text
    aCust.c8fir = street.text
    aCust.c9sec = secondLine.text
    aCust.c10ar = area.text
    aCust.c11pc = postcode.text
    aCust.c12cos = cost.text
    aCust.c13fq = frequencyNumber.text
    aCust.c14fqt = frequencyType.text
    let DF = NSDateFormatter()
    aCust.c15das = DF.dateFromString(startDate.text!)
    //Do Pics in a minute & next date in a minute
    aCust.c17notes = notes.text

    //print("Desc = \(picRound.image?.description)")

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Save Successful")
    } catch {
        print("Save Unsuccessful")
    }
}
```

What is the code to link this customer with the correct Round?

Thanks, I am very new to core data and really would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use a predicate on your fetch request, with a format like

```
NSPredicate(format:"custRoundRel = %@", xxxx)
```

where `xxxx` is the `Round` instance.

You can also just use the `roundCustRel` relationship depending on what you want to do with the `Customer` instances and how many there are.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, so when I save a customer entity with its corresponding attributes how do I link it to the correct round name?

Comment: you need to have that `Round` instance, either already or fetch it by name, then just set it to the relationship: `yyyy.custRoundRel = xxxx` (where `yyyy` is your new `Customer` instance

Answer (score -1):

You create `Customer` objects in the same way you create other managed objects. To link a customer with the correct `Round` object, just set the to-one relationship (Core Data will automatically set the reverse relationship for you).

```
newCustomer.round = round
// or, with your arcane attribute names
newCustomer.custRoundRel = theDesiredRoundObject
```

To get to the customers of one specific round, you do not need fetch requests or predicates.

```
round.customers
// or, with your arcane attribute names
round.roundCustRel
```